# Nginx version equivilant of fairly complex apache rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, security, rewrite, wordpress

I'm having a bit of a nightmare trying to get a specific apache rewrite rule block working on nginx.

It is for blocking and securing a Wordpress admin. Have tried a couple of online tools, but these have not managed to help. Any help would be great.

This is the original rule..

```
RewriteRule ^something-login/?$ /wp-login.php?fddf8778tbb [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)/wp-login\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^fddf8778tbb
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=postpass
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$

RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /not_found [R,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^loggedout=true
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wp-login.php?fddf8778tbb [R,L]
```

And this is what I have for nginx

```
location / {
    index       index.php;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {

    # IF ARG STRING NOT SET
    if ($args != "fddf8778tbb") {
        # DIE
        return 301 https://$server_name/404;
    }
}

location /something-login {
    rewrite ^/something-login/?$ /wp-login.php?fddf8778tbb redirect;
}
```

Comment: Most of the stuff in the Apache config is redundant and unnecessary. Your existing config looks fine (except for the return 301, but you knew about that already).

Comment: It's all pretty much working, however the actual wordpress login (after you throw in the password/username) kicks you out. I suspect I am missing the cookie check.

Comment: You'd probably be better off using two factor authentication, or limiting access to admin by IP.

Comment: @Tim I think I am likely to go down the route of limiting access by IP.